# Web page that dynamically draws contours at user specified elevation?

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, elevation, contour

How might I setup a web page that will draw dynamically contours and/or hypsometric tints at a user specified starting elevation and/or interval?

Example scenario: flood hazard modelling. The web page supplies the elevation model and widget controls, the user asks the page "what would be underwater at *n* meters?" Assume the horizontal extent of elevation model would be small, less than 2000x2000 cells/pixels.

[image: Simulated flood display of user entered parameters]

Client side processing preferred. I know to how to set up a processing pipeline in ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS to accomplish this ([derive contours](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/how-to-derive-contour-lines-from-a-surface.htm) and [contour plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/) respectively) but I want to take myself out of the middle and let people do this for themselves. The interaction pattern of *"input parameters >> send for processing >> wait for results >> 'oh, what about N instead?' >> ... "* has too much friction.

ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Online are available, Mapbox is an option, but a self contained setup that could run on any reasonably modern web environment is preferred.

Comment: Not sure of anything client side, but server side WPS would look pretty similar (in that you wouldn't need to transfer the terrain, so it'll be roughly equally fast, or slow, probably). At least geoserver has a contour operation that you can call from SLD: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html

Comment: I tried this years ago, I ran into the problem that the river flowed downhill and from the North to the South, with a drop of 25 feet, So a flood of 10 foot, would be at a different elevation in the North then in the South. Trying to draw contours on this slanted floodplain was a nightmare, it was easier to run the model for each 2 foot change and then combine the data after. Because of the time it took we did not run the model live.

Comment: A short overview of 3 javascript contouring libaries: http://emptypipes.org/2015/07/22/contour-comparison/. MarchingSuares.js looks promising, though it may not scale to what I've described here.